# Displaying different image based on direction of resize

Tags: javascript, html, onresize

I have two images. I am trying to display one when the browser resizes left, and the other when it resizes right.

```
    function adjustDirection() {
        var last_pos_x = window.screenX;

        if ( last_pos_x < window.screenX) {
            document.getElementById("logo").style.backgroundImage = "url('logoRight.png')";
        } else if (last_pos_x > window.screenX) {
            document.getElementById("logo").style.backgroundImage = "url('logoLeft.png')";
        }
    }
    window.onresize = adjustDirection;
```

However, it seems like my function only begins to works if `last_pos_x` is declared outside of the function, which is clearly wrong because it will only store `window.screenX` from load.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution is use jQuery. Store the posX value in DOM and retrieve it

HTML

```
<div id="aaa" data-posx="0"></div>
```

Javascript

```
function adjustDirection() {
        var last_pos_x = $("#id").attr("data-posx");
        $("#id").attr("data-posx",window.screenX);
        if ( last_pos_x < window.screenX) {
            document.getElementById("logo").style.backgroundImage = "url('logoRight.png')";
        } else if (last_pos_x > window.screenX) {
            document.getElementById("logo").style.backgroundImage = "url('logoLeft.png')";
        }
    }
    window.onresize = adjustDirection;
```

New code with just js:

```
function adjustDirection() {
    var last_pos_x = window.screenX;
    return function() {
        if (last_pos_x < window.screenX) {
            document.getElementById("logo").style.backgroundImage = "url('logoRight.png')";
        } else if (last_pos_x > window.screenX) {
            document.getElementById("logo").style.backgroundImage = "url('logoLeft.png')";
        }
        last_pos_x = window.screenX;
    }
};
var z = adjustDirection();
window.onresize = z;
```

Comment: OP asking for vanilla

Comment: @DeepakDavid yes, could you write that in js? without html?

Comment: 'code' document.getElementById('item1').setAttribute("data-posx","0");

Comment: function adjustDirection() {
        var last_pos_x = window.screenX;
  return function(){
      if ( last_pos_x < window.screenX) {
            document.getElementById("logo").style.backgroundImage = "url('logoRight.png')";
        } else if (last_pos_x > window.screenX) {
            document.getElementById("logo").style.backgroundImage = "url('logoLeft.png')";
        }
      
      last_pos_x =  window.screenX;
    }
};
var z= adjustDirection();
window.onresize = z

Comment: can u edit in ur comment so i can see the formatting plz